# Cross validating lasso regression in R

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation, lasso, glmnet

The R function cv.glm (library: boot) calculates the estimated K-fold cross-validation prediction error for generalized linear models and returns delta. Does it make sense to use this function for a lasso regression (library: glmnet) and if so, how can it be carried out? The glmnet library uses a cross-validation to get the best turning parameter, but I did not find any example that cross-validates the final glmnet equation.

Comment: It certainly makes sense, & although LASSO only optimizes over one (hyper-)parameter, if you want to get the best estimate you can of out-of-sample performance you need an outer cross-validation loop. See [Can you overfit by training machine learning algorithms using CV/Bootstrap?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/29377/17230) & the cited papers.

Comment: It's recommended to use glmnet rather than glm esp. if you're doing CV. If I recall, glm package becomes painful to use. Also, cv.glmnet exposes more parameters than cv.glm.

Answer (score 13):

An example on how to do vanilla plain cross-validation for lasso in `glmnet` on `mtcars`
 data set.

1. Load data set.
2. Prepare features (independent variables). They should be of `matrix` class. The easiest way to convert `df` containing categorical variables into `matrix` is via `model.matrix`. Mind you, by default `glmnet` fits intercept, so you'd better strip intercept from model matrix.
3. Prepare response (dependent variable). Let's code cars with above average `mpg` as efficient ('1') and the rest as inefficient ('0'). Convert this variable to factor.
4. Run cross-validation via `cv.glmnet`. It will pickup `alpha=1` from default `glmnet` parameters, which is what you asked for: lasso regression.
5. By examining the output of cross-validation you may be interested in
   at least 2 pieces of information:

   - lambda, that minimizes cross-validated error. `glmnet` actually provides 2 lambdas: `lambda.min` and `lambda.1se`. It's your judgement call as a practicing statistician which to use.
   - resulting regularized coefficients.

Please see the R code per the above instructions:

```
# Load data set
data("mtcars")

# Prepare data set 
x   <- model.matrix(~.-1, data= mtcars[,-1])
mpg <- ifelse( mtcars$mpg < mean(mtcars$mpg), 0, 1)
y   <- factor(mpg, labels = c('notEfficient', 'efficient'))

library(glmnet)

# Run cross-validation
mod_cv <- cv.glmnet(x=x, y=y, family='binomial')

mod_cv$lambda.1se
[1] 0.108442

coef(mod_cv, mod_cv$lambda.1se)
                     1
(Intercept)  5.6971598
cyl         -0.9822704
disp         .        
hp           .        
drat         .        
wt           .        
qsec         .        
vs           .        
am           .        
gear         .        
carb         .  

mod_cv$lambda.min
[1] 0.01537137

coef(mod_cv, mod_cv$lambda.min)
                      1
(Intercept)  6.04249733
cyl         -0.95867199
disp         .         
hp          -0.01962924
drat         0.83578090
wt           .         
qsec         .         
vs           .         
am           2.65798203
gear         .         
carb        -0.67974620
```

Final comments:

- note, the model's output says nothing about statistical significance of the coefficients, only values.
- l1 penalizer (lasso), which you asked for, is notorious for instability as evidenced in [this](http://blog.datadive.net/selecting-good-features-part-ii-linear-models-and-regularization/) blog post and this stackexchange [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67915/explanation-for-unstable-lasso-regression-coefficients?rq=1). A better way could be to cross-validate on `alpha` too, which would let you decide on proper mix of l1 and l2 penalizers.
- an alternative way to do cross-validation could be to turn to caret's `train( ... method='glmnet')`
- and finally, the best way to learn more about `cv.glmnet` and it's defaults coming from `glmnet` is of course `?glmnet` in R's console )))

Comment: Nice answer. .. it is also worth running the CV multiple times and averging the error curve (see?cv.glmnet) to account for the sampling.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov VERY USEFUL!

Comment: Hi,
I know that this is an old post, but I wanted to ask you a question. You mention that the model's output says nothing about statistical significance of the coefficients, so how do you determine that they are significant or not?

Comment: @JunJang "There is no statistical significance for coefficients" is the statement from authors of the package, not me. This statement is given, I do not remember exactly, either in one of the book of the package authors or in the package's vignette. In such a case, instead of saying coefficients significant or not, you'd rather say they are "useful" or not in explaining target through cross validation.